# Can I make the animationplayer to continues playing when changing scenes?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I know it's not the best way to make a day/night cycle but I did use animation player and canvas modulate to make it
Now I just need it to continue playing when I get in another scene. Like I don't want it to restart it everytime I change scene
Like what is the best way to do that?

I didn't try many things as I'm new

I did use autoload , but yeah I don't know the rest

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessted, you put it on an [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html). Since they persist when you change the current scene, any `AnimationPlayer` in an autoload would continue playing. For the `AnimationPlayer` to work it also needs access to whatever it animates, so you are going to put all that in a scene, and then register that scene as an autolaod. *Yes, autoload can be scenes, they don't have to scripts.*

Comment: Ohhh makes a lot of sense now. But that's what I did, I made a 2dnode and inside it, there is a animationplayer and a canvas modulate and then I animated it and saved it as a scene and put it in autoload but didn't work, I know I'm doing something wrong but can't really tell where